# Microsoft Edge Unexpected Page Redirect Without Interaction

Tags: web-browser, microsoft-edge

Upon opening Microsoft edge, I clicked on a homepage Fox News article about a new bill being introduced. While reading, I looked down and checked my phone, and looked up to see my browser redirecting to a weird ".xyz" page that had one of those fake "Critical Edge error" messages and a spammy popup box about contacting a presumably fake support number. I closed Edge and reopened.

The weird thing is that I wasn't going through any sketchy sites or anything and didn't click anything to set this off. What possibilities are there in terms of if there is a malware issue on my computer that caused this, or is there an Edge exploit I don't know about to hijack pages to display a different page? I tried to copy the url before exiting, but even though I thought I hit copy, when I pasted in this post it pasted the previous thing I'd had saved to my clipboard.

Comment: One of the likelier possibilities is a malicious ad on the site you were browsing. There isn't enough information to tell what actually happened, though.

Comment: See also [Malvertising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malvertising). It is not uncommon that major advertising networks are affected by this specifically if they use real-time ad bidding. And when these big ad networks are affected the big web sites are affected too. Bit as Ghedipunk said already - this is just a guess and there are not enough details to be sure.

Comment: Thanks this seems plausible! Sorry I don't have more details but I wasn't really paying attention to see what happened.